# How do we know that this formula is always positive

Tags: probability

How do we know that $2V(X)-2Cov(X,Y)+2V(Y)>0$ for all random variables X and Y

Comment: It can also take value $0$.

Comment: $$\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]\geq 0$$ and equality is achieved in very few cases.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Not sufficient, here the variances are multiplied by $2$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use that variance is non-negative and that covariance is bilinear and symmetric.

$$\begin{align}0 & \leq\textsf{Var}(X-Y) \\& =\textsf{Cov}(X-Y,X-Y) \\ &=\textsf{Cov}(X,X)-2\,\textsf{Cov}(X,Y)+\textsf{Cov}(Y,Y)\\&=\textsf{Var}(X)-2\,\textsf{Cov}(X,Y)+\textsf{Var}(Y) \\ &\leq 2\,\textsf{Var}(X)-2\,\textsf{Cov}(X,Y)+2\,\textsf{Var}(Y)\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you tell me how you go from the second equation to the third equation?

Comment: You mean the one stating $Cov(X,X)=Var(X)$? If it is the former you mean then there is it used that $Cov$ is bilinear.

Comment: I mean this one $\text{Covar}(X-Y,X-Y)=\text{Cov}(X,X)-2\text{Cov}(X,Y)+\text{Cov}(Y,Y)$

Comment: I got it now. It's ok. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Covar(X-Y,X-Y)=Cov(X,X)-Cov(X,Y)-Cov(X,Y)+Cov(Y,Y)

Comment: Also it is used that $\text{Cov}$ is symmetric: $\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\text{Cov}(Y,X)$.

Comment: @Graham Kemp Professional and beautiful looks. Thanks Graham.